# too many digits after decimal point

Tags: angularjs

Value is displaying as 364.80000000000001. I want to display it as 364.80.
So, I used value.toFixed(2); It is displaying value as 364.80. but in html, I have used input type=number.

It is displaying error as [ngModel:numfmt] Expected `364.80` to be a number.

Is there any other way to solve this issue

Comment: maybe you could try to make your input field with step "any" like this = <input type="number" step="any">.. but im not sure if I understand you problem correct..

Comment: Have you tried with:{{ var1 | number:2 }}

Comment: @ChristopherSupertramp , i tried with step="0.01" but failed

Comment: input field is allowing to display 364.80000000000001 but not allowing 364.80

Comment: after i used .toFixed(2), value type is changing to string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `string-to-number` on your input field:

`<input type="number" string-to-number ng-model="x" ... />`

More info can be found here: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/numfmt

Answer (score 1):

You can use filters for such thing.

Angular have this filter for numbers. you can use it this way.

```
{{ number_expression | number : fractionSize}}
```

For more information use link below.

[angular number filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number)